# Facebook like is broken, adds a trailing # to the final url

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, scrape

I'm running my site on Cargo Collective and  trying to have likes per page.  I cannot modify the code in the head tag only within the body tag.

When i debug a page i get the following;

```
Response Code   206
Fetched URL http://www.iamneuron.com/Break-this
Canonical URL   http://www.iamneuron.com/Break-this
URL for Likes   http://www.iamneuron.com/#Break-this
Final URL   http://www.iamneuron.com/#Break-this
```

I can't figure this out and i have been searching for a while now.  Even if i explicitly specify the url rather than leaving the code to figure it out, facebook still adjusts the url to one that doesn't work with the trailing #.

Originally i was trying to create the like code via facebook but i have now switched to this which works better with cargo but still produces the same error:
http://randomcodescraps.tumblr.com/post/1363402555/js-dynamic-like-button-on-cargo-collective-projects

Anybody any ideas? Thanks in advance btw!

Answer (score 0):

Your page doesn't have any OG tags that Facebook can use. And those that are in your page are commented out. Add proper OG tags and then use the link tool to check you tags and see if still have the same problem.

Comment: the og tags are meta tags that must be put into the head though?

Comment: Yep, add the OG Meta tags to the `<head>`

Comment: This is not possible on cargocollective!

Comment: Must be a way to extend the functionality or you're stuck mate.